# How to make relation with all_auth/rest_auth user to some model. with cookie/token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using all_auth and rest_auth along with Angular. I have a model called Campaign

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hashtag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    message = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    sale_limit = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateField(default=now_plus_30)
    product_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

and a view as

```
class ListCreateCampaign(APIView):
    """
    List all Campaigns or create one.
    """

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CampaignSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I don't want to pass user_id from via API, how do I get the user details and inject it in request.data

Comment: You can access the current user from `request.user`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be, make `user` field optional in serializer by making `required=False`. Then pass the user while calling `.save()` method of serializer like `.save(user=request.user)`. For more info http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save